# Unable to archive source code directory in terraform/terragrunt: archive has not been created as it would be empty

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

The error occured when trying to use `data "archive_file"` to zip the source code directory, the path of the directory is correct, but the console does not recognize the source code file inside the directory.

Below is the code snippet in `cloud_functions.tf`:

```
data "archive_file" "source" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "../../../source/"
  output_path = "../../../source/temp/test_source.zip"
}
```

Below is the error:

```
│ Error: Archive creation error
│ 
│   with data.archive_file.source,
│   on cloud_function.tf line 28, in data "archive_file" "source":
│   28: data "archive_file" "source" {
│ 
│ error creating archive: error archiving directory: archive has not been
│ created as it would be empty
```

The folder structure looks like below:

```
.
├── env
│   └── npe
│       └── cloud-function
│           └── terragrunt.hcl
│           └── vars.hcl
├── modules
│   └── cloud-function
│       └── cloud_function.tf
│       └── variables.tf
├── source
│   └── main.py
├── .gitlab-ci.yml
└── terragrunt.hcl
```

When using `resource "google_storage_bucket_object"` to upload the single `main.py` the error is similar by saying "no such file or directory".

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question solved, the source folder needs to be placed under the module folder.

```
.
├── modules
│   └── cloud-function
│       └── source
│           └── main.py
│       └── cloud_function.tf
│       └── variables.tf
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).